# Set two items color at same time in android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I need to change the colour of two recylerview items at same time,based on the selection of user.
for example :- We have 4 options available in recylerview.
case 1:- User clicks the right option than change the recylerview item colour to green
case 2:- User clicks the wrong option than change the recylerview item colour to red and correct option to green. and rest to remain white.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxTjB.jpg)
Reference from image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLVWV.jpg)

JSON Response for options:-

```
    "options": [
                    {
                        "options": "big trouble",
                        "answer_id": 73,
                        "option_image": "",
                        "is_correct":"0"

                    },
                    {
                        "options": "right ",
                        "answer_id": 74,
                        "option_image": "",
                        "is_correct":"0"
                    },
                    {
                        "options": "none",
                        "answer_id": 75,
                        "option_image": ""
,
                        "is_correct":"1"
                    },
                    {
                        "options": "no error",
                        "answer_id": 76,
                        "option_image": "",
                        "is_correct":"0"
                    }
                ]
```

Rest is the normal recylerview and adapter .

Comment: post some of your code here

Comment: I wouldn't use recyclerview for those options. You have only four options, which seem to be stable and all visible. You don't need recycling. (Unless I'm missing something)

Comment: Can you please post some code @OyaCanli

Comment: @UsamaAltaf  again posted

Comment: as @OyaCanli mentioned there is no need to use recyclerview

Comment: We don't  know exact 4 options. The options can vary from 4, and can  have text & images.

Answer (score 0):

```
        holder.mCardItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        
            if(---)  //True Condition
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00C853"));
            else if (---) // False Condition
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
            else    //Nurtal Condition
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: it works only when we click. Please check my referenced images above.